# CodeIgniter is_cli_request() returns false when run from cronjob

Tags: codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface

Here is my cronjob's command

> php /home/toolacct/public_html/index.php cronjob fetch_emails

Here is my CodeIgniter cronjob controller

```
class Cronjob extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        die($this->input->is_cli_request()?'T':'F');
        $this->load->model('cronjob_model');
    }   

    public function fetch_emails() {
        $this->cronjob_model->fetch_emails();
    }

    public function index_popularity() {
        $this->db->query('CALL update_email_data_popularity()');
    }
}
```

The cronjob says "F"
Why?

---

A side note: If I create a function like this

```
function is_cli_request() {
    return isset($_SERVER['SHELL']);
}
```

It returns true or false correctly, while CodeIgniter always returns false.

Comment: Did you forgot to call the PHP executable first? Like: /path/to/php /home/toolacct/public_html/index.php cronjob fetch_emails

Comment: No I am, my bad I forgot to show that part.
The fact it's saying "F" means it's running okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Input Class Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::is_cli_request) says that `$this->input->is_cli_request()` uses the STDIN constant to check if its running on the command line.

Try using the command line version of PHP instead (php-cli), since the STDIN constant doesn't appear to be set while running the standard PHP executable (php).

Comment: Broken link for input Class Documentation

Comment: Thanks @shakaran, fixed broken link! :)

Comment: Documentation link seems to be broken again. Here you go: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::is_cli_request

Comment: Cheers @DrewAPicture, the link has been updated again.