# Codeigniter is_cli_request() stops cpanel cron job from working

Tags: codeigniter

On my website I use cron job on cpanel.

I have this code below in the construct area of controller but it stops the cpanel cron job from working.

```
if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
    show_error('Direct access is not allowed');
}
```

> **Question** Do I need the code above. if I use my cpanel cron job? I just want to make it more secure.

```
<?php

class Cron extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
            show_error('Direct access is not allowed');
        }

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->model('members_model');
    }

    public function message()
    {
        $admin_email = $this->config->item('email_host');
        $admin_email_pass = $this->config->item('email_password');
        $companyname = 'Riwaka';

        $config = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mail.yourdomain.co.nz',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => $admin_email,
            'smtp_pass' => $admin_email_pass,
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $members = $this->members_model->get_approved_members_for_cron_job();

        if ($members) {

            foreach ($members as $member) {

                if ($member['approved'] == '1' && $member['approved_email_sent'] == '0')
                {

                    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

                    $this->email->clear();

                    $this->email->from($admin_email, 'Admin');

                    $this->email->to($member['email']);

                    $this->email->subject($companyname .' Account Approved');

                    $this->email->message('test');

                    $update = array(
                        'approved_email_sent' => '1',
                    );

                    $this->members_model->update_approve_email_send($member['email'], $update);

                    $this->email->send();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent direct access from a webpage:

you need to add this line

```
/* deny direct call from web browser */
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) die('Permission denied.');
```

with CI 3.0 you can

> Make your cron-jobs inaccessible from being loaded in the URL by
>   checking the return value of `is_cli()`.

`is_cli()` returns TRUE if the application is run through the command line and FALSE if not.

as by my comment, the cpanel cron job pattern is:

> /usr/bin/php /var/www/website/public_html/cli.php controller method

,

see docs [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#is_cli)

related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285034/codeigniter-is-cli-request-returns-false-when-run-from-cronjob)

Comment: On the top line on in the construct area'

Comment: Still same issue stops the script from running.

Comment: replace your if clause with this line

Comment: check also a previous answer of mine to yhis subjects, maybe you find help there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490

Comment: I have just updated the path `**** php-cli /home/myusername/public_html/subdomain/index.php Cron message` is that correct

Comment: if it matches the pattern `/usr/bin/php /var/www/website/public_html/cli.php controller method`, then yes, that works for me... you need to get your cpanel absolute path, you might need to ask your service provider...

Answer (score 0):

Solved now. [CodeIgniter Cron Job through Cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558830/codeigniter-cron-job-through-cpanel)

It seem to be a issue from path I had used. On cpanel before I had

```
php --silent http://mysubdomain.mydomain.co.nz/cron/message
```

That was not working proper if I wanted to use this code to prevent access

```
if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
   show_error('Direct access is not allowed');
}
```

### So now I changed to

```
php-cli /home/myusername/public_html/mysubdomain/index.php Cron message
```

All works fine now