# Codeigniter CLI does not log

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface

I have the following function which updates the status of my vacancies (based on dates) and logs the amount of vacancies that got a change, it looks like this:

```
//Function used to check the statusses of every vacancy and update it accordingly
    function checkVacanciesStatusses()
    {
        // this function can only be called from the command line
        if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) {
            echo "Access is only allowed from the command line";
            return;
        }

        $this->load->model('vacancy/vacancies_model');
        $this->load->library('managers/LogManager');

        $affected0 = $this->vacancies_model->updateToStatus0();
        $this->logmanager->createCronLog("updateToStatus0", $affected0);
        $affected1 = $this->vacancies_model->updateToStatus1();
        $this->logmanager->createCronLog("updateToStatus1", $affected1);
        $affected2 = $this->vacancies_model->updateToStatus2();
        $this->logmanager->createCronLog("updateToStatus2", $affected2);
    }
```

This is put in a cronjob to be executed every 30minutes, like so:

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/index.php cli/cron checkVacanciesStatusses >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The code for the createCronLog in my logmanager looks like this:

```
class LogManager {

    protected $CI;

    // We'll use a constructor, as you can't directly call a function
    // from a property definition.
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Assign the CodeIgniter super-object
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');
        $this->CI->load->model('logging/logCron_model');
    }

    /**
     * Creates an entry in the log_cron table
     *
     * @param string $method            the name of the method executed
     * @param array  $amount_updated    the amount of rows updated during the method the cron logged for
     *
     * @return int                      row id
     */
    public function createCronLog($method, $amount_updated)
    {
        //Create a LOG entry
        $entity = new stdClass();
        $entity->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $entity->hostname = gethostname();
        $entity->pid = getmypid();
        $entity->user = get_current_user();
        $entity->uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $entity->method = $method;
        $entity->amount_updated = $amount_updated;

        return $this->CI->logCron_model->add($entity);
    }
}
```

The thing which I cannot wrap my head around is that the vacancy updates (so the model calls) work perfectly. But the logging does not work.

When I comment the if clause which checks if it is a cli_request, and I manually browse to the function, the vacancies gets updated **AND the logging works!**

What is happening? 
It is not giving any errors or whatsoever, it just works when executed manually.

Comment: check my answers, maybe they help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910528/2275490 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190095/2275490

Comment: @Vickel Thanks for your post! I checked the thread before. I know the database access is working because the other model call is working fine. I also use the same if check but I use is_cli_request() instead of is_cli() , i tested with both, result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem was that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` is not available in a CLI environment...

Comment: How we can do this?